# Angular2 highcharts fails to render data to the chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Am creating a pie chart using data from http request butthe data is never rendered in a pie chart

I have tried

in the html

```
  <div class="col-md-4" *ngIf="overallready">
    <chart [options]="overallinsp" class="chart"></chart>
  </div>
```

in typescript code i have

```
this._reportService.getOverview(utctime:number) //performs http request
.subscribe(
   let dtaval = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.totalinspectiondata));
     console.log(dtval)
      this.overallinsp = {
        credits: {
            enabled: false
          },
          chart: {
                 ...
                  type: 'pie'
              },
              title: {
                  text: ...
              },

              series: [{
                 name: 'Brands',
                 colorByPoint: true,
                 data:dtval
            }]  

  }

  this.overallready = true;
  )
```

The above console.log() produces

```
[{"name":"Bulker delivered","y":0},{"name":"Normal delivered truck","y":4}]
```

setting the value manually in the series works that is

```
        series: [{
         name: 'Brands',
          colorByPoint: true,
          data:[{"name":"Bulker delivered","y":0},{"name":"Normal delivered truck","y":4}]
            }]
```

What could be wrong since manually setting the data output works but referencing it fails to work?

Comment: add `console.log(res.totalinspectiondata)`  to debug the issue

Comment: produces: [{"name":"Bulker delivered","y":0},{"name":"Normal delivered truck","y":4}]
            }]

Comment: even changing  let dtaval = res.totalinspectiondata; still doesnt work.

Comment: Do type checking using `typeof` before and after processing `res.totalinspectiondata`

Comment: thanks for the insight the typeof returned a string ive converted it to an object and now it works